# How to change highlighted color in Adobe Reader easily

Tags: pdf

I like to highlight in Adobe documents but its pretty cumbersome in Adobe Acrobat reader. It's not easy to change color for the next line you want to highlight.

Is there at least a shortcut where I can bring up the dialog and change color?

Currently I have to highlight with the same color last used (instead of able to pick new color), do the highlighting, then select the new highlighted region, right click on it, go to properties, then change color.